# Using SAS macro to import multiple txt files with sequential names

Tags: sas

I have 4 txt files that need to be loaded to SAS and save them as 4 sas files. Here are how the text files look like: cle20130805.txt, cle20130812.txt, cle20130819.txt and cle20130826.txt . I used a % Do loop under % Macro in order to get the 4 files imported with only one invoke of the Macro. So Here is my code:

```
%macro cle;
  %do i=20130805 %to 20130826 %by 7;
   Data cleaug.cle&i;
     infile "home/abc/cle&i..txt" dlm= '|' dsd firstobs=1 obs=100;
     input a_no b_no c_no;
   run;
 %end;
%mend cle;
%cle
```

I am expect to have 4 sas file saved with only invoke the marco once. However it just can't run successfully. Any ideas where am I doing wrong in the code?

Thanks,

Comment: Please include error messages or unexpected/undesired results if you want us to understand "just can't run successfully".

Comment: two sets of warning from SAS server: 1) NOTE 49-169: The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS release.  Inserting white space between a quoted string and the succeeding identifier is recommended. 2)WARNING: The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 bytes long.  You might have unbalanced quotation marks.

Comment: Two sets of warning is not helpful.  What those warnings _say_ might be.  Post your complete log (obfuscated for real file names if needed).  In the question, not in comments.

Comment: BTW, I changed dlm='|' to dlm="|" and I still get the same two sets of warning.

Comment: Those warnings indicate a problem not explicitly obvious from the code above -somewhere else you probably have what it says, unbalanced quotations.  Start your session over.

Comment: Problem is solved! The thing is I missed a "/" in the infile statement . Since I am running SAS on Unix server so I have to have "/" to get the right directory of my files. When I referred my file location correctly: infile "/home/abc/cle&i..txt" dlm= '|' dsd firstobs=1 obs=100; The whole marco runs successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend you try to write one macro to import all four files.  Either it will be a specific macro you only ever use once - in which case you could just write this by hand and save the time you've already spent - or it will be something you have to modify every single month or whatever that you use it.

Instead, make the macro something that does precisely one file, but includes the information needed to call it easily.  In this case, it sounds like you need one parameter: the date, so 20130805 or whatnot.  Then give it a reasonable name that really says what it does.

```
%macro import_files(date=);
  Data cleaug.cle&date.;
     infile "home/abc/cle&date..txt" dlm= '|' dsd firstobs=1 obs=100;
     input a_no b_no c_no;
   run;
%mend import_files;
```

Now you call it:

```
%import_files(date=20130805)
%import_files(date=20130812)
%import_files(date=20130819)
%import_files(date=20130826)
```

Just as easy as the macro you wrote above, even hardcoding the four dates.  If the dates are predictable in some fashion, you can generate the macro calls very easily as well (if there are more than 4, for example).  You could do a directory listing of the location where the files are, or call the macro from a data step using CALL EXECUTE if you really like looping.

Comment: Thanks Joe. This is what I have done at the beginning. However I will need to import even more files to SAS in future for example all the August files from 20130805 to 20130831. So, invoke macro one by one might be a little bit tedious. That's why I am testing if a %do loop under the marco would help. Thanks,

Comment: If you're doing that, then this macro is probably a better idea - it's easier to put in a dataset (or excel file/text file/etc.) the dates you might want to import than to try to use %do which is clunky.  I'd also strongly suggest putting the files into *one* dataset (which you can do with wildcards in the filename perhaps) rather than 30 separate datasets, as it's likely you can do your analysis just as well from 1 with BY <datevar>; rather than doing same analysis 30 times.

Comment: Hey Joe, could you elaborate a little bit about the "directory listing" and "call execute" that you mentioned in your first comment? Thanks,